# Regex, the preg_match is matches no matter what string i am typing

Tags: php, regex

i'm attemping to create a code which allows me to use html tags but without any attributes.

this is my code :

```
$dom->loadHTML("<p>a</p>");
$post = $dom->saveHTML();
if (!preg_match("/<.+\s[^A-Za-z0-9]?>/", $post)) {
    echo "matches";
}
```

for some reason i'm getting the "matches" message even if the tag is empty from attributes.

Comment: what do you mean by ***attitudes*** ? did you mean attributes? also, when you use `saveHTML()` html, header and body tags are included.

Comment: attributes, my bad. when i'm alert the data from the $post i get the <p>a</p>. @PedroLobito

Comment: why dont you  want to use HTML parser?

Comment: Please post a sample of what you need to match and not to match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pattern is not matching the HTML string in your question because the pattern requires the characters following a less-than character to be followed by a whitespace character. There are no whitespaces in the HTML tags in your string, thus it does not match, thus "matches" is echoed as you negate the result of the preg_match function.

If your HTML string is `<p >a</p>` or `<p>a</p >` it would match (`<p >` and the whole string respectively). Hopefully this answer points you in the right direction.